# how to change boot logo without using fastboot

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, boot, fastboot

I know how to change the boot logo(logo.bin) from fastboot, but the problem is how can I change the boot logo without using fastboot.

I can't go to fastboot mode because I think my device(ME-702) doesn't support fastboot (I tried adb reboot bootloader but no benefit).
My device has not any recovery too.

Is there any way to change the logo in adb mode?

Comment: do you have adb or fastboot already installed on your computer?

Comment: i have adb! but fastboot won't working :(

Comment: `adb shell su -c dd if=/sdcard/logo.bin of=/dev/block/boot-device/by-name/logo`